# How to Get the Values from DataRow using Row Name

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I have a Table with following format :

```
Name                  Value
------------------------------- 
IsFirst           0
skateType         0
IsApplied         1
```

I have a Class `DetailsClass` and need to update it's object based on the value from table.

```
public class DetailsClass
    {
        [DataMember]
        public bool IsFirst { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public bool skateType { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public bool IsApplied { get; set; }
    }
```

For now I am doing :

```
 foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
                {
                    if (String.Equals(row["Name"].ToString(), "IsFirst"))
                        VDetail.Base = dataTable.Rows[0]["Value"] != null ?   Convert.ToBoolean(dataTable.Rows[0]["Value"]) : false;

                    else if (String.Equals(row["Name"].ToString(), "skateType"))
                        VDetail.Type = dataTable.Rows[1]["Value"] != null ? Convert.ToBoolean(dataTable.Rows[0]["Value"]) : false;

                    else if (String.Equals(row["Name"].ToString(), "IsApplied"))
                        VDetail.IsApplied = dataTable.Rows[2]["Value"] != null ? Convert.ToBoolean(dataTable.Rows[0]["Value"]) : false;
                }
```

But is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: how many rows are in the table? If there is not a huge amount of data maybe it make sense to populate a `Dictionary<string, bool>` first

Answer (score 0):

**Interpretation 1**

A way to access the field by name is row.Field("columnName"). Just replace "long" with the column's data type, and columnName with the correct name.

**Interpretation 2**

If what you are after is a way to map the data from your table to your object, then I would suggest this:

```
var detail = new DetailsClass();
foreach (var row in dataTable.Rows)
{
    if (row.Field<string>("Name") == "IsFirst")
        detail.IsFirst = row.Field<bool>("IsFirst");
    else if (row.Field<string>("Name") == "skateType")
        detail.skateType = row.Field<bool>("skateType");
    else if (row.Field<string>("Name") == "IsApplied")
        detail.IsApplied = row.Field<bool>("IsApplied");
}
```

I've assumed that your data type in the table is a bit field since the class object has bool.